# Store String with SQL code inside a register in SQLite3

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, store

Is there a way to store a large Strings containing SQL code (like substrings) inside a sqlite3 column in a table?? (avoiding sql injections and all security stuff I could be forgetting) Not looking for something like stored procedures. Just store text with sql queries inside (for something like an inform use).

Need to store a string like this (witch contains SQL code like substring):
"bla foo bla foo bla bla bla SELECT * FROM TABLE bla foo bla foo foo foo bla bla"

Comment: What is a "sqlite3 register"?

Comment: Don't know if it exists like that or with that name. Register = column inside a table

Comment: You just insert a row with the desired values? You *are* using parameters in your inserts and binding values to those instead of building strings with values directly in them if doing this programmatically, right?

Comment: You can store any strings, which includes strings that contain SQL code. I fail to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

SQL offers a canonical way to store queries.  These are called views, which are created as:

```
create view <name> as
    <query here>;
```

You can read about them in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html).  This may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I think I was not clear specifying my problem.

I need to store a tex like this: "bla bla bla bla foo foo foo SELECT * FROM TABLE bla bla bla foo foo foo bla INSERT INTO()VALUES bla bla bla bla"   Inside a register in a table.